# syntax error, unexpected $end in php

Tags: php

I am getting the following error in one of my php file
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/qualitet/public_html/game/create.php on line 1

What could be the problem? I checked all the if else.

Comment: 7 questions, 0% acceptance. Not good.

Comment: Posting (a part of) the code might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser encountered an unexpected end of your source code. So you’re probably missing some closing curly bracket or something similar.

Comment: You might need to check whether you have short codes turned on as some plugins or themes use them and your development settings in php.ini might have them disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> I checked all the if else.

I don't think you did :) Try commenting out all of them, and bringing them back one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Check if all your curly braces are closed.  It can also be caused by short open tags

Answer (score 0):

You've probably missed a closing bracket (`}`) somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use a binary search to find this.

Save your file to a new file and then remove large chunks (1/2) at a time, until the code compiles.  That last chunk removed is the one with the missing }

Answer (score 0):

I thought I also add to this ticket, since I've had a similar problem and there wasn't anything visible that could cause it, however after calling one of the methods after instantiation of the class there was an invisible character a after closing semicolon, which was causing the same error - once I've removed semicolon and everything after it, then put the semicolon back - everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check whether you have short codes turned on `<?` as some plugins or themes use them and your development settings in php.ini might have them disabled.

**Production**

short_open_tag = On

**Development**

short_open_tag = Off

See the PHP manual for more info regarding use of `<?` and `<?php`

This often explains why local development server operation differs from live server due to PHP configuration differences.